# Boundedness of a naive integral operator

Tags: operator-theory

Define integral operator $J:L^2[0,1] \to L^2[0,1]$,
$$Jf(x) := \int_0^x f(s) ds.$$

I am wondering if the following equivalence holds,
$\|Jf\|_{L^2} \simeq \|f\|_{H^{-1}}$,
where $\|\cdot\|_{H^{-1}}$ is the norm on $H^{-1} = (H^1)'$, i.e. the dual space of classical Sobolev space.

Comment: Yes, that works essentially, you can just look at the Fourier coefficients. It would probably be safer to take $\|Jf\|_2^2 + |\widehat{f}(0)|^2 \simeq \|f\|_{H^{-1}}^2$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Would you please show me the detail? I know $\|Jf\|_2 \leq C \|f\|_2$, but I cannot figure out how this links to the dual norm.

Comment: Use that $\|f\|=\|\widehat{f}\|$ and $\widehat{f'}=ik\widehat{f}$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling So because $\widehat{Jf} = -\frac{1}{ik} \widehat{f}$ and the dual norm in Fourier basis $\|f\|_{-1}^2 = \sum k^{-2} \widehat{f}_k^2$, we actually show $\|f\|_{-1}^2 = \|J f\|_{L^2}^2$?